# Deserialize JSON to an object or an array using RestSharp

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

I'm working on a Xamarin Project.  Basically, I want to receive data from the API and display it. I'm using RestSharp for this.

Here is my code for the API request.

```
string test;
test = "yAHO0SsAmjJi1qTZGcK3sMHHIhWTN4Yq";
string s = string.Format("http://192.168.1.4:3116/api/user/getuser/{0}", test);

client = new RestClient(s);
request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
IRestResponse response2 = client.Execute(request);
```

This is the JSON object I receive.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "token": "yAHO0SsAmjJi1qTZGcK3sMHHIhWTN4Yq",
    "email": "some email",
    "password": "testpassword",
    "currentCompany": "some company",
    "currentRole": "Software Developer",
    "date": "Something",
    "name": "Some name",
    "lastName": "Some surname",
    "headLine": "Some text",
    "education": "University of Hotshots",
    "country": "Who cares",
    "imageLocation": "Some url"
}
```

This is the class I created for it using the website: json2csharp.com/

```
class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string CurrentCompany { get; set; }
    public string CurrentRole { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string HeadLine { get; set; }
    public string Education { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string ImageLocation { get; set; }
}
```

How I can change my code such that I can deserialize the response to an instance of the above class, so that I can use it to process the data? I read the posts here and tried the solutions, but they didn't seem to be working for me.  So, I posted this question.

Using an array is an option as well; I can work with it.  For reference, see PHP's `$array = json_decode($somepostrequest, true)`, which turns the JSON object into an associative array. You can just call the object's `$array['email']`.

Comment: research Json.Net

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [Newtonsoft.JSON](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) to deserialize JSON to a object (and vice versa). Its pretty simple and free to use. There also is a NugetPackage available.
When installed, you just need the following line to get the wanted object.

```
User userObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(jsonString);
```

Comment: Thanks, when I saw jsonString it made me understand it better, that I had to use response2.Content.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the generic overload of `client.Execute()`.  RestSharp will use its internal serializer to deserialize the JSON:

```
var response2 = client.Execute<User>(request);
User user = response2.Data;
```

An example of this is shown on the [Recommended Usage](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Recommended-Usage) wiki page on RestSharp's GitHub site.

Granted, RestSharp's internal serializer isn't as full-featured as Json.Net, but it doesn't look like you need anything fancy here.